# Prove that converge..?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $ a_n \geq 0 $ and  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\lt \infty $. Prove that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}(a_n)^ \frac{1}{2}< \infty $$

Comment: I tried cauchy, but I can't conclude

Comment: When you ask a question, write also your attempts ;)

Comment: $ab\le{1\over2}(a^2+b^2)$ (since $0\le (a-b)^2$).

Answer (score 5):

Cauchy Schwarz inequality $$\sum_{n}\frac{a_{n}^{1/2}}{n}\leq\left(\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n}a_{n}\right)^{1/2}<\infty.
 $$

Comment: mmmm is not enough

Comment: @Sudosu Why not? What's the problem?

Comment: I'll rewrite my proof, and could you review it

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that you don't need the inner product on $l^2$. You can also apply the regular old $\mathbb{R}^n$ Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_n}n^{-1}$ to show the partial sums are bounded, then use the monotone convergence theorem to show they converge.